# Using RegEx to Capture All Links & In Between Text From A String

Tags: php, regex

```
<Link to: http://www.someurl(.+)> maybe some text here(.*) <Link: www.someotherurl(.+)> maybe even more text(.*)
```

Given that this is all on one line, how can I match or better yet extract all full urls and text? ie. for this example I wish to extract:

`http://www.someurl(.+)` . `maybe some text here(.*)` . `www.someotherurl(.+)` . `maybe even more text(.*)`

Basically, `<Link.*:.*` would start each link capture and `>` would end it. Then all text after the first capture would be captured as well up until zero or more occurrences of the next link capture.

I have tried:

```
preg_match_all('/<Link.*?:.*?(https|http|www)(.+?)>(.*?)/', $v1, $m4);
```

but I need a way to capture the text after the closing `>`. The problem is that there may or may not be another link after the first one (of course there could also be no links to begin with!).

Comment: It might be easier to try and `preg_split` using a pattern for a full URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "<Link to: http://www.someurl(.+)> maybe some text here(.*) <Link: www.someotherurl(.+)> maybe even more text(.*)";
$string = preg_split('~<link(?: to)?:\s*([^>]+)>~i',$string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.someurl(.+)
    [1] =>  maybe some text here(.*) 
    [2] => www.someotherurl(.+)
    [3] =>  maybe even more text(.*)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
preg_match_all('~<link\b[^:]*:\s*\K(?<link>[^\s>]++)[^>]*>\s*(?<text>[^<]++)~',
               $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    printf("<br/>link: %s\n<br/>text: %s", $match['link'], $match['text']);
}
```